# Symfony2 - inject code before rendering template

Tags: php, symfony, smarty

I added [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle) to my Symfony2 application. It's working good but I would like to change left (default: `{`) and right (default: `}`) delimiters to `[` and `]`. To do this I need to execute following code:

```php
$smarty = $container->get('templating.engine.smarty')->getSmarty();
$smarty->left_delimiter = '[';
$smarty->right_delimiter = ']';
```

How to do this before rendering template in controllers? I suppose I need to use EventListener but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Your can usage request listener in Kernel.

If smarty engine have method setLeftDelimiter and setRightDelimiter, your can create a CompilerPass for your bundle, get definition and add call methods.